# Ubuntu too slow while extracting files and etc

Tags: command-line, minecraft

i'm using ubuntu via terminal. i have a minecraft server in ubuntu. i'm trying to download a world for my server it's nearly 5 GB and i downloaded that file to my pc then i tried to send it to ubuntu with BitVise. i'm waited so much and it was saying 60+ hours for a 5 GB file. it's way too much. then i changed my mind and i tried to download it on ubuntu. then somehow after 2 - 3 hrs work time, i did it but i downloaded it as zip. and i have to extract it for my project. i tried a lot of extract commands on terminal but it didn't work (some errors and more). right now i have no idea what to do. i just wanna send it faster from my computer. what can i do? it's just impossible to send.

Comment: Wired or Wireless? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting and [edit] your question. Do not click "Add comment".

Comment: Did you read `man unzip file`?

Comment: To give any answer we would need an exact overview over your whole network infrastructure (Hardware and Software). Could you add this in detail to your question?

Comment: Please [edit] your Question and show us `uname -a;uptime;free;ip l | grep $(ip r | awk '/default/ {print $5}' ) | awk '{print $2, $4, $5}';id`. Do not use "Add comment".